# How to access and compare which file was change in git pre receive hook

Tags: git, githooks

I'm new to git hooks, now I have a simple request which needs me to check the config file in my project.

For example, I have a spring-boot config file: `application.yml`, It's content is:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
```

In the `master` and `release` branch, I need to ensure the file is

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: prod
```

While in the `dev` branch, I need it to be:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

Now I need a pre-receive hook to check If the `application.yml` was modified. If it was changed, I need to check if the correct branch corresponds to the correct file content. Otherwise, the push behavior will be rejected.

I'm using GitLab and I knew where to put the file. But I don't know how to write the script or if my request can be satisfied using a pre-receive script. I spent the whole day reading the git doc but I get little help. If anyone has a solution or any document reference would be appreciated.

Comment: Commits are just snapshots, so no commit ever *changes* any file. A file in snapshot X and "the same file" (whatever that may be) in snapshot Y might differ, though. If you'd like to know if the file named `path/to/file` in snapshots X and Y differ, compare them (or use `git rev-parse` to get their hash IDs, if an exact-match is all that you care about). The trick is picking snapshots X and Y, really—and for *that* you may need to read GitLab documentation, depending on whether they're giving you a raw Git pre-receive hook, or something else.

Comment: Note that in a pre-receive hook, *no new commits exist on any branch names yet*. The Git level pre-receive hook runs *before* the branch-name update is allowed, and its job is to decide *whether to allow the push to proceed*. So you read lines from standard input, one at a time; each line has a proposed change to some reference name. You must decide whether the change is to be allowed.

Comment: Note further that any one given commit may be present in *multiple branches*, so the idea of requiring some file `path/to/application.yml` to have form A in branch B1 and form B in branch B2 is probably a bad plan: it's possible that commit C is in both B1 *and* B2 *at the same time*, and hence file `path/to/application.yml` in commit C cannot meet both requirements.

Comment: @torek  So I couldn't get any branch information in the pre-receive hook. I got it. Another question is that if there are any ways that I can know which file was changed in the following push behavour?  Because I only care about my application.yaml file. Or I can use `git rev-parse`  which you have mentioned

Comment: You *do* get the name of the proposed ref update, and if that has the form `refs/heads/*` (matches `refs/heads/` and goes on), that's a branch name. So if the input stream includes, say, `deadcafe feedbag5 refs/heads/jean/baptiste/emanmuelle/zorg`, that's a proposal to change the branch name `jean/baptiste/emannuelle/zorg` from commit `deadcafe` to commit `feedbag5`. But requiring that a file have some particular *form* just because it's going to appear in that *branch* is unwise **as a strategy**. It's not that you *can't* do it, it's that you *shouldn't*.

Comment: And, again, files aren't *changed* by any `git push`. A `git push` simply changes *which commit some name locates*. Any *changes* occur because you are comparing commit X (for some hash ID X) to commit Y (for some hash ID Y). Commits just hold *snapshots*. The set of commits that are find-able from a branch name is determined by the commit hash ID stored *in* that branch name. Each commit itself stores the hash ID(s) of its parent(s), so that Git can work backwards.

Comment: When you start writing pre-receive hooks, you are delving into Git at its deeper levels, where it's just a kind of special file system. For (much) more about this—you really need to know *all* of it—see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: @torek I will set the `master` and `dev` branch into protected branches. So they wouldn't be changed easily.  The reason why I have to do this is that when we develop locally, we have to use the `dev` config file. If I push it to `master`, then the config file must be `prod`.  If a specific branch corresponds to the correct file, then it's less likely to make mistake.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for one day, I found the answer that I want.
Since I'm new to git hook, this is my first time using it. I think I need to learn more about git
Thank you very much for your suggestion @torek

```bash
#!/bin/bash

oldrev=$1
newrev=$2
refname=$3
z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

echo 'start git pre receive checking...............'
while read oldrev newrev refname; do
    # Get a list of all objects in the new revision
    objects=`git ls-tree --full-name -r ${newrev}`
    echo "in loop"
    # Get the file names, without directory, of the files that have been modified
    # between the new revision and the old revision
    
    if [ "$oldrev" = $z40 ] ; then
                # handle the case when new branch was create
        oldrev="4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904"
    fi

    if [ "$newrev" = $z40 ]; then
                # handle the case when branch was deleted
        newrev="4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904"
    fi
        # get file name
    objects=`git ls-tree --full-name -r ${newrev}`
    
    git diff --name-only $oldrev $newrev | while read file; do
        
                # grep file name, find the file that I need
        object=`echo -e "${objects}" | egrep "(\s)${file}\$" | egrep 'application.properties$' | awk '{ print $3 }'`
        # If it's not present, then continue to the the next iteration
        if [ -z ${object} ]; 
        then 
            echo "not application.properties : ${file}"
            continue; 
        fi
                # get the file that I want
        echo "get change file: ${file}"
        echo "get remote refname: ${refname}"
                # check the remote banch
        if test -z "$(  echo $refname | egrep 'release$'  )"; then
                echo "ref不是release."
                                # checkout the file content
                if test -z "$( git show $newrev:$file | egrep 'dev' )"; then
                        echo "properties file didn't have dev, please check it"
                        exit 1
                else
                        echo "properties file got dev, yes! "
                        exit 0
                fi

        else
                echo "remote ref is release."
                if test -z "$( git show $newrev:$file | egrep 'prod' )"; then
                        echo "properties has no prod，please check"
                        exit 1
                else
                        echo "properties got prod, yes"
                        exit 0
                fi

        fi
        echo "out put changed config file"
        #  git show $newrev:$file
    done
done
```